# Exception: Limit Exceeded: Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am an individual user, and I use Apps Script to share a Google Sheets file with others. Recently, when running the Apps Script code, I received an error message

> Exception: Limit Exceeded: Drive.

Additionally, when trying to share the file manually, I also encountered an error message stating that the sharing limit had been exceeded. How to address this issue? If upgrading my account is necessary, please provide instructions on how to do so.

[image]

[image]

I have tried disabling all Chrome extensions, clearing browsing data, logging out and logging back in, and using incognito mode, but there have been no results.